# Delete user control and all of its children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` which contains several nested other `UserControl`s. They are defined in xaml code and each have a `Name` property so I can access them via that in code.

```
<UserControl Name="parentControl" ...>
    <local:ChildControl Name="childControl" />
</UserControl>
```

Now from `parentControl`'s code I want to destroy all child controls, so I want to destroy `childControl` and all of its child controls it may have.

I tried just setting

```
childControl = null;
```

but one of its child controls still works as if nothing happened (it is still writing to a log file indicating its functioning state). I tried running `GC.Collect()` which didn't have any effect.

The reason why I have to do it like this (or in a similar way) is that I am using a framework that instantiates `parentControl` and creates its UI by doing that. My problem is that my UI does not get destroyed correctly when its EOL is reached.

Comment: The exact answer depends on your exact XAML. If you really have a `ChildControl` as Content of parentControl (which is what you are showing here) set its Content to null. Otherwise clear the Children property of the Panel that contains the ChildControl elements.

Comment: Setting `Content = null` worked for me. Thank you! If you post it as answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
parentControl.Children.Clear();
```

Comment: I tried `((Panel)this.Parent).Children.Clear();` but that does nothing either.